# Blender API: Return value of bpy.data.objects(ID).show_bounds and .bound_box

Tags: python, objects

I am getting started with the Blender Python API and there is something I do not understand. Lets say I have an object called "myObject" and I wanted to get its dimensions, then I type

```
bpy.data.objects["myObject"].dimensions
```

in the python console and get the result. The API http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object states, that an object also has a bound_box. But if I type

```
bpy.data.objects["myObject"].bound_box
```

simply the command I typed is returned! Why is that and how could I have known from the doc of the API? Also, when I type

```
bpy.data.objects["myObject"].show_bounds
```

it only returns "false". Why? If I go to the object properties panel and click "Bound" the bounding box is drawn. Why does that work and doing the same (?) via the console does not?

Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I figured out that one simply has to set show_bounds to True to be able to see the bounding box of an object. However, I have still not figured out how to see the values of the bounding box

Answer (score 4):

`Object.bound_box` does not contain mathutils-types like Matrix or Vector, it's a plain property array of float[3] which has no representation format like other types do.

You need to iterate over all elements and print them, e.g.:

```
for b in bpy.context.object.bound_box:
    print(b[:])

# (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
# (-1.0, -1.0, 1.0)
# (-1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
# (-1.0, 1.0, -1.0)
# (1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
# (1.0, -1.0, 1.0)
# (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
# (1.0, 1.0, -1.0)
```

Or make a list of Vector objects:

```
[Vector(b) for b in bpy.context.object.bound_box]
```