# Selecting faces in Python

Tags: python, faces

For the sake of simplicity, lets start with the default screen.

How would you go about selecting faces in Python?
Top, Bottom, Sides?

```
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()  
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')  
bpy.ops.mesh.select_face_by_sides(0)
```

This seems to select everything.
I can't find a subscriptable face[0] anywhere...

I also know you can do:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')  
bpy.ops.mesh.select_nth(nth=6, skip=1)
```

but I'm not too savvy on the whole 'nth' thing.
I had it at one point, but I don't recall what I did.

set nth= to the number of faces,
then use skip= to pick different faces?

Is that the only method, or can I find a simple list of faces somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

`bpy.ops.mesh.select_face_by_sides` allows to select faces which are matching an amount of sides (border edges). It also needs named arguments:

Examples:

```
#Selects faces bordered by 3 edges
bpy.ops.mesh.select_face_by_sides(number=3)

#Selects faces bordered by more than 3 edges
bpy.ops.mesh.select_face_by_sides(number=3, type='GREATER')
```

The object's faces are stored in *polygons* (`obj.data.polygons`).

So for instance, for top, bottom and side faces you can use:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

def NormalInDirection( normal, direction, limit = 0.5 ):
    return direction.dot( normal ) > limit

def GoingUp( normal, limit = 0.5 ):
    return NormalInDirection( normal, Vector( (0, 0, 1 ) ), limit )

def GoingDown( normal, limit = 0.5 ):
    return NormalInDirection( normal, Vector( (0, 0, -1 ) ), limit )

def GoingSide( normal, limit = 0.5 ):
    return GoingUp( normal, limit ) == False and GoingDown( normal, limit ) == False

obj = bpy.context.object

prevMode = obj.mode

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)

#Selects faces going side
for face in obj.data.polygons:
    face.select = GoingSide( face.normal )

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=prevMode, toggle=False)
```