# Delete the upper surface of a cylinder with the api

Tags: modeling, python

I want to delete the upper surface of a cylinder with the python api.

I tried this code:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices=32, radius=3.0, depth=0.02, calc_uvs=True, enter_editmode=False)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode   = 'EDIT')

bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type= 'FACE')

bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='ONLY_FACE')
```

The result is that Blender deletes both surfaces the upper and the under. Any suggestions how to solve this?
Thx

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75517/selecting-faces-in-python answer by lemon

Answer (score 1):

**Bmesh script.**

can add primitives using `bmesh`.  The equivalent of add cylinder is `bmesh.ops.create_cone(...)` with both radii set to match.

As with the mesh operator the default for ends is NGON fill.

The top face will have a normal that is in +Z direction.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/96121

Test script, run in OBJECT mode.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context

TOL = 1e-5

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Open Cylinder")
bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_cone(
        bm,
        cap_ends=True,
        segments=32,
        diameter1=3,
        diameter2=3,
        depth=0.02,
        calc_uvs=True,
        )

f = next(
        (
            f for f in bm.faces
            if f.normal.angle((0, 0, 1)) < TOL
        ),
        None
        )
        
if f:
    bm.faces.remove(f)        

        
bm.to_mesh(me)
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Open Cylinder", me)
context.collection.objects.link(ob)
```

For the case of a TRIFAN filled end would remove the middle vert, to remove the edges and faces in one fell swoop.

Alternatively could create cylinder without faces and fill only the bottom edge loop.